# Updating Mailgun's composer library for PHP API since their SSL update

Tags: php, composer-php, mailgun

Mailgun recently upgraded their SSL cert and as a result my mailing script stopped working. I believe it might be because I am using an older version so I am trying to update it.

When I run the following on the command line;

```
php composer.phar require mailgun/mailgun-php php-http/curl-client guzzlehttp/psr7
```

I am asked for a version constraint:

> Please provide a version constraint for the mailgun/mailgun-php requirement:
>
> Please provide a version constraint for the php-http/curl-client 
>   requirement:
>
> Please provide a version constraint for the guzzlehttp/psr7 requirement:

Can anyone tell me what I should use and how I should specify a version?

I haven't used composer much (only for this library).

The `Mailgun` support has been slow, vague and intermittent at best!

Comment: If your Mailgun API hits have stopped working as a result of them changing their SSL cert, then the fix is likely not addressable via PHP source. You probably have an outdated PHP/curl.

Comment: Can you share your `composer.json`?

Comment: I know that Mailgun library is out of date, I am trying to update it with the command above. Here is my composer.json file;
{
    "require": {
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "~1.7"
    }
}

Comment: What @AlexHowansky said. You need to update your PHP/curl.